# Not able to get all the search results from each page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to automate a scenario: From amazon.com search for iphone and get the title of all the search results. In each page I do see that there are 18 search results and on the last page that is on 20th page it gives sometimes less than 10 results.

I am able to get the results but the numbers are not consistent. Sometimes I do get 18 for a page but then on other pages I get less than 18 as well.

I did try wait with expected conditions like presenceOfAllElementsLocated and visibility as well but both of them did not work. `numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan` did work but again the last page that os 20th page gives less than 10 results.
One more thing, using Thread.sleep also provide correct results. I am using Java. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit adding the code what I did:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        browserUtil.openURL("https://amazon.in");
        ElementUtils elementUtils = new ElementUtils(driver);

        By searchField = By.id("twotabsearchtextbox");
        By searchButton = By.id("nav-search-submit-button");
        By eachResult = By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@cel_widget_id, 'MAIN-SEARCH_RESULTS')]//h2//span");
        By nextButton = By.className("s-pagination-next");

        elementUtils.sendKeysToTextField(searchField, "iPhone");
        elementUtils.clickOnElement(searchButton);
        System.out.println(elementUtils.getAllElementsTextBySize(eachResult, 17));

        while(!Objects.equals(elementUtils.getWebElement(nextButton).getAttribute("aria-disabled"), "true")){
            elementUtils.clickOnElement(nextButton);
            System.out.println(elementUtils.getAllElementsTextBySize(eachResult, 17));
        }

        browserUtil.closeBrowser();
```

My elements utility looks like this:

```
public ElementUtils(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20));
        actions = new Actions(driver);
    }

    public WebElement getWebElement(By locator){
        return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
    }

    public List<WebElement> getWebElements(By locator){
        return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(locator));
    }
    public List<WebElement> getWebElementsBySize(By locator, int size){
        return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(locator, size));
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the wait time, when Selenium lands on any new page, or you can use the below mechanism and manipulate these codes after reaching every search result page.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().scriptTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
```

Comment: That does not work neither does pageLoadTimeout because the page is getting loaded without any lag. If I run the code by putting a debugger it works, putting a thread.sleep after landing on each page works, or if use the ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan